# how to make a hidden markov model in R programming

Tags: r

I want to do a HMM for a DNA sequence using R. the aim of this is to be able to search a small sequence in a larger sequence.
I´m trying to use HMM-Rpackage but I don´t know how to define which are the states or the symbols.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

States is the hidden state which you do not observe and you want to guess. Therefore, The transition matrix is the evolution of States (e.g. if the length of States is n, then the transition matrix will be of nxn)
Symbols is the actual observable state. The emission matrix is the probability of observing a symbol given a state. Therefore, the emission matrix will be of size nxm, being m the length of the vector of symbols.

An example to reproduce this will be the one implemented in the package using the dishonest casino explanation:

> A dishonest casino uses two dice, one of them is fair the other is loaded. The probabilities of the fair die are (1/6,...,1/6) for throwing ("1",...,"6"). The probabilities of the loaded die are (1/10,...,1/10,1/2) for throwing ("1",..."5","6"). The observer doesn't know which die is actually taken (the state is hidden), but the sequence of throws (observations) can be used to infer which die (state) was used.

In our case, we are going to make that once the dice is changed, at least it will be used three times on a row. For that, the following code has been implemented:

```
library(HMM)



States<- c("die1_1","die1_2","die1_3","die2_1","die2_2","die2_3") 
Symbols<-1:6 
Trans<-matrix(c(0.5,0.5,0,0,0,0, 
                0,0.5,0.5,0,0,0, 
                0,0,0.5,0.5,0,0, 
                0,0,0,0.5,0.5,0, 
                0,0,0,0,0.5,0.5, 
                0.5,0,0,0,0,0.5),6,6, byrow =TRUE)
Emission<-matrix(NA,6,6) 
Emission[1:3,]<- rep(1/6,6) # Fair dice 
Emission[4,]<- c(1/10,1/10,1/10,1/10,1/10,1/2) 
Emission[5,]<- c(1/10,1/10,1/10,1/10,1/10,1/2) 
Emission[6,]<- c(1/10,1/10,1/10,1/10,1/10,1/2)# Fair dice 
startprobs<- c(0.5,0,0,0.5,0,0) # It starts in position 1 or 4, which means first dice first throw or 2nd 


myhmm<- initHMM(States, Symbols, startprobs, Trans, Emission) 
##Sampling 
simHMM(myhmm, 50)

# $`states`
# [1] "die2_1" "die2_2" "die2_2" "die2_2" "die2_2" "die2_3" "die1_1" "die1_2" "die1_2"
# [10] "die1_2" "die1_3" "die1_3" "die1_3" "die2_1" "die2_2" "die2_3" "die2_3" "die2_3"
# [19] "die2_3" "die1_1" "die1_2" "die1_2" "die1_3" "die2_1" "die2_1" "die2_2" "die2_3"
# [28] "die1_1" "die1_2" "die1_2" "die1_3" "die2_1" "die2_2" "die2_2" "die2_2" "die2_3"
# [37] "die1_1" "die1_1" "die1_1" "die1_2" "die1_3" "die2_1" "die2_2" "die2_2" "die2_2"
# [46] "die2_2" "die2_3" "die1_1" "die1_1" "die1_2"
# 
# $observation
# [1] 6 6 6 6 6 6 1 5 5 2 6 3 6 6 3 4 4 6 6 4 4 4 3 6 6 6 4 2 4 3 2 1 6 3 6 6 3 1 3 3 4 5
# [43] 6 6 6 6 6 6 4 6
```

I hope it helps understanding the basics of the package. Cheers !